# How can I pass a sparse matix from Perl to R?

Tags: perl, r, sparse-matrix

I have a very sparse Perl matrix  (array of arrays), where `undef` values are equivalent to zeros. It has 10-1000 rows and up to 100k columns. It looks like:

```
$ARRAY1 = [
            [
              ( undef ) x 1069,
              1,
              ( undef ) x 47,
              1,
              ( undef ) x 11,
              2,
              ( undef ) x 50,
              1,
              ( undef ) x 23,
              1,
              ( undef ) x 6033,
              ...
            ],
            [
              ...
            ],
            ...
          ]
```

... as I said - very sparse.

I want to use this matrix in an R script (see [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099322)). One way is to print the table to a file from Perl - one line per row, and print `0` anytime we run into `undef`.

But perhaps there is a better, more compact way to pass this sparse matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a moderately hard problem.

I think I would start by *making simple things possible* to rephrase a Perl slogan:

1. Learn about the two or three sparse matrix package for R like slam, SparseM, ....
2. Pick one you prefer and learn how to efficiently build a sparse matrix, presumably from triplets such as `(x,y,value)` to encode `value` at position `(x,y)`.
3. Write Perl code to emit your sparse matrix in that form to a tempfile.
4. Read that tempfile in R and build your sparse matrix.

Fancier and faster cross-language serialization can come later. It's not a trivial problem.

Comment: If the relevant sparse matrix packages expose a C or C++ interface, it would likely be possible to wrap that for use by Perl. OTOH, that'd not only require Perl, R, and C proficiency but also XS and R-guts fu, so it's probably not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 0):

If you print those zeros into file, that's a lot of unnecessary printing for perl and reading and parsing for R.  The more common way to serialize a sparse matrix like this is to provide only the dimensions (if necessary) and the non-zero elements' indices and values.  So your intermediate serialized data might look like:

```
80000 200
1069 0 1
1117 0 1
1129 0 2
...
```